# How to show a modal before redirecting on next page when clicked on a submit button in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider I have two models: `Employer` and `Jobs`.

Employer has created an account to post a job and filled in his phone number too. And when he fills up a new job and click on post job button(Submit button). I want to check whether the mobile number that he entered is already verified or not and if it isn't I want a modal or a lightbox to popup where I ask him to missed call on a certain number and as soon as he does that page is redirected to jobs index page. And if he wants to cancel the verfication he can do that but the page will be redirected to nowhere, it'll still be on form page.

But I don't know how to do this. Please, help!

Comment: We don't know how to help you unless you show some code!

Comment: Looks the way is handle the form `onsubmit` event. What did you try so far? It's hard to help without the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check whether the mobile number that he entered is already verified or not

I would recommend this to be implemented at the model level, which you can then initialize through an `ajax` call:

```
#app/models/employer.rb
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many  :jobs
   validates :phone_number, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end

#app/models/job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :employer
end
```

I don't know your backend... and it also seems you're using Rails 3. You definitely need to look at updating that (considering [Rails 5 is almost out](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/)).

This will give you the validation at the application-level, which will allow you to send a request to your controller & have the response provided by Rails directly:

```
#app/views/jobs/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @job, remote: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html
   def new
      @job = Job.new
      @job.save
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:error", "form#new_job", function(xhr, status, error) {
   alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a `onsubmit` event on form tag.

Call a method `onsubmit` of form and fire an ajax from the method. Check whether the mobile number is verified or not from controller and return `true` or `false`. Then from Ajax success function check the value(true/false) and if the value is false show modal and return false else return true.